# No android menu group in android studio 3.0

Tags: android-studio

I've updated `android studio` to 3.0 and `android` group disapeared from `tools` menu.
[image]

I have SDK installed

[image]

I need `android studio` for `ionic` - I'm beginner and  don't know that tool

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can determine (by experimenting) group and barriers are not supported in Constraint layout 1.0.2 which is what is used by default in Android Studio 3.0.
That is the the latest version of Constraint layout didn't ship with the latest version of Android Studio.
It is still in beta - beta 3 released on Oct 12th.
If you want to use it
open the projects build.gradle file and change it to read:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta3'
```

Only the last line needs changing i.e. from 1.0.2 to 1.1.0-beta3. You will need to resync the project and then you will see group and barriers in the right click context menu.